# Chrome Book - google chrome browser not detected accessibility service event

Tags: google-chrome, androidappsonchromeos

- we try to detect google chrome browser url's and user events.
- we using the Accessibility service to monitoring the event on chrome browser.
- we using the accessibility event functions to detect browser events.
- accessibility event detect all other browsers. but, not in google chrome browser.